# Extract/Remove portion of an Integer or string with random digits/characters in R

Tags: r, substr

Say I have an integer

```
x <- as.integer(442009)
```

or a character string

```
y <- "a10ba3m1"
```

How do I eliminate the last two digits/character of integer/string of any length in general ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`substr` returns substrings:

```
substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-2)
# [1] "4420"
substr(y, 1, nchar(y)-2)
# [1] "a10ba3"
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you @josilber, I was doing this in a really stupid way .... substr(y,nchar(y)-2,nchar(y)-2)

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the value is an integer, then you can just divide by 100 and convert back to integer (drop the decimal part).  This is probably a little more efficient than converting it to a string then back.

```
> x <- as.integer(442009)
> floor(x/100)
[1] 4420
```

If you just want to remove the last 2 characters of a string then `substr` works.

Or, here is a regular expression that does it as well (less efficiently than `substr`:

```
> y <- "a10ba3m1"
> sub("..$", "", y)
[1] "a10ba3"
```

If you want to remove the last 2 digits (not any character) from a string and the last 2 digits are not guaranteed to be in the last 2 positions, then here is a regular expression that works:

```
> sub("[0-9]?([^0-9]*)[0-9]([^0-9]*)$", "\\1\\2", y)
[1] "a10bam"
```

If you want to remove up to 2 digits that appear at the very end (but not if any non digits come after them) then use this regular expression:

```
> sub("[0-9]{1,2}$", "", y)
[1] "a10ba3m"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Greg Snow, the regex look was useful, but output of  sub("[0-9]?([^0-9]*)[0-9]([^0-9]*)$", "\\1\\2", y) removes the "3" from y <- "a10ba3m1" and returns "a10bam" . Am i Missing something ?

Comment: @user3006691, yes the last 2 digits in that string are the 3 and the 1 so both are removed.  If you only want digits at the very end of the string removed, then the regex is simpler.